# Есть ли в Intellij idea поисковик, который найдёт код в External Libraries?

Tags: intellij-idea, библиотеки, поисковые-системы

Дело было так:

1. Мне выдали очень огромный проект.
2. В проекте нужно было найти, где мапится один из запросов.
3. Этот запрос мапился в классе, который находился в одном из джарников, в **external libraries.**
   Данный класс, когда я его открыл, имел жёлтенькую полоску: `"Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 55.0 (Java 11)"`

Понятное дело, `Edit -> Find in path`, найти эту строчку кода не могло (даже в scope). А я в ручную нашёл за очень много часов, которые жалко.

**Вопрос:** есть ли в Intellij Idea где-то функционал, который разыщит нужную строчку коду среди jar'ников, в **External Libraries?** А если нет, можно ли как-нибудь пропарсить External Libraries, чтобы найти нужный файл?

Comment: `Crtl`+`Shift`+`F`. `Scope` -> `All Places`. У меня так прекрасно ищет.

Comment: @Tsyklop,а у меня не ищет там.